# Can't get Radio Buttons to work in ng-repeat with font-awesome labels

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, font-awesome

I am struggling with getting some Font Awesome labels to work with radio buttons in an AngularJS ng-repeat. I know there is an issue with the `$scope` inside ng-repeat, and I have copied the examples of several work-arounds that mentioned using `$parent`, but none of the fixes have seemed to work for me thus far.
I want row clicking to still toggle the radio buttons as well.

**JSFIDDLE:** http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/16692/

**HTML**

```
<div ng-app>
    <div ng-controller="TodoCtrl">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row" ng-repeat="i in integrations" ng-click="$parent.isChecked = !$parent.isChecked">
                <div class="col-xs-1">
                    <input id="int{{$index}}" type="radio" ng-model="$parent.isChecked" name="radiointegration" ng-value="i.isChecked" />
                    <label for="int{{$index}}"></label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-6" style="padding-top:10px">{{i.text}}</div>
                <div class="col-xs-5" style="padding-top:10px">{{i.isChecked}}</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
function TodoCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.integrations = [{
        text: 'one',
        isChecked: false
    }, {
        text: 'one',
        isChecked: false
    }, {
        text: 'one',
        isChecked: false
    }, {
        text: 'one',
        isChecked: false
    }, {
        text: 'one',
        isChecked: false
    }];
}
```

**CSS**

```
.row:nth-of-type(even) {
    background: #f3f8fe;
}
input[type=radio] {
    display: none;
}
/* to hide the radio itself */

input[type=radio] + label:before {
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    display: inline-block;
}
input[type=radio] + label:before {
    content: "\f1db";
}
/* unchecked icon */

input[type=radio] + label:before {
    letter-spacing: 10px;
}
/* space between radio and label */

input[type=radio]:checked + label:before {
    content: "\f00c";
    color: $harmonyColorGood
}
/* checked icon */

input[type=radio]:checked + label:before {
    letter-spacing: 5px;
}
/* allow space for check mark */

label {
    margin-top: 7px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    font-size: 25px;
}
label:hover,
.row:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    background: #f5f5f5;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somehow you handled your radio buttons like checkboxes.

I've removed some unnecessary variables in your fiddle, please check if this is the effect you need?

```
<div class="row" ng-repeat="i in integrations">
    <div class="col-xs-1">
        <input id="int{{$index}}" type="radio" ng-model="$parent.checked" name="radiointegration" ng-value="i.text" />
        <label for="int{{$index}}"></label>
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/16693/)

Comment: Can the rows still be clickable to toggle the checkbox? like `checkbox =! checkbox` on `.row`?

Comment: Yes, but you do `$parent.checked = i.text`. Stop treating them like checkboxes @@

Comment: That doesnt seem to apply the radio button when clicking a row, am I missing something? And sorry for thinking in checkbox mode :S http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/16694/

Comment: Sorry I had wrong variable... why cant `isChecked` work but `text` does?

Comment: well `isChecked` works too, but assigning true or false into the model doesn't help you identify which item is actually being clicked. As you can see I also changed all the `text` to be unique, else it can't be identified correctly. In real world we normally give them data unique ids so we can target them for sure.

Comment: So the checkboxes work and show up fine, but when in my controller when I pass this on my $scope.checked doesn't update. the $parent.checked updated while selecting them, but controller doesn't update?

Comment: It should update. I have put {{checked}} on the main scope to track whether it is updated or not.

Comment: I had to do controller as. The $parent was three levels up since this is a directive for my page.